# How remove duplicate menu in personalize on wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have problem with my new template on the base "Twenty Seventeen". I used wordpress on my Page. When I changed position page logo i can see good result but in card personalize i can see - 2 logo and 2 edit mark for menu.

I wanted to get the effect logo before the menu on the same line.

In function.php on the last line i added:

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'wpsites_add_logo_nav_menu', 10, 2 );
function wpsites_add_logo_nav_menu( $menu, stdClass $args ){
    if ( 'top' != $args->theme_location )
        return $menu;


    return the_custom_logo().$menu;
}
```

In result I can see [good structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtXUX.png) but when i go to personalize, I can see 
[double logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1msvP.png)

Thanks for all help.

EDIT:
The problem disappeared, when I removed other logo in header and removed cache.